# Vector - value with k-occurences first

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, computer-science

This is my first post and hope I'm not doing anything wrong.
I am trying to write a program that find the first value of the vector that reach k-occurrences in it.

For example, given this vector and k=3:

1 1 2 3 4 4 2 2 1 3

I would see 2 as output, because 2 is the first number reaching the 3rd occurrence.

The following code is what I tried to run, but somehow output is not correct.

---

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        vector<int> vettore;
        int k;
        int a,b,i;
        int occ_a;
        int occ_b;

        cout<< "Write values of vector (number 0 ends the input of values)\n"; 
        int ins;
        cin>>ins;
        while(ins)
        {
            vettore.push_back(ins);     //Elements insertion
            cin>>ins;
        }
        cout<<"how many occurrences?\n"<<endl;;
        cin>>k;
        if(k>0)
        {
            int i=0;
            b = vettore[0];
            occ_b=0;

            while(i< vettore.size())
            {

                    int j=i;
                    occ_a = 0;
                    a = vettore[i];
                    while(occ_a < k && j<vettore.size())
                    {
                        if(vettore[j]== a)
                        {
                            occ_a++;
                            vettore.erase(vettore.begin() + j);
                        }
                        else
                            j++;
                    }
                    if(b!=a && occ_b < occ_a)
                        b = a;
                    i++;

            }
            cout << b;   //b is the value that reached k-occurrences first
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

---

Hours have passed but I have not been able to solve it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a good problem to use to practice using the debugger that came with your development environment. Compile the program with minimal optimization and whatever debugging options are available, then run the program in the debugger. Use the debugger to step through the program line by line and keep an eye on the variables being used. As soon as you see the program do something you don't expect, stop and figure out why it happened. Usually the unexpected is a bug.

Comment: Side note: take a look at `std::map` and `std unordered_map` a `map<int, int>` can make very short work of frequency count-type problems.

Comment: Side note: In C++ we declare variables when they are used, not at the top of their scope

Comment: Why would you get `2` as the output? `1` also occurs 3 times and it comes before `2` in the array.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The k-th time of 2  occurs before the k-th time of 1.:) It is how I have understood the assignment.

Comment: @user4581301 I will try to figure out how to use the debugger properly! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Vlad from Moscow has understood the assignment, sorry, but maybe my english is not that good :(

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 thanks for the side note, I'll improve my code writing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is difficult to read because you are declaring variables where they are not used. So their meanings is difficult to understand.

Also there is no need to remove elements from the vector. To find a value that is the first that occurs k-times is not equivalent to to change the vector. They are two different tasks.

I can suggest the following solution shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3 };
    size_t least_last = v.size();
    size_t k = 3;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i + k <= least_last; i++ )
    {
        size_t count = 1;
        size_t j = i;

        while ( count < k && ++j < least_last )
        {
            if ( v[j] == v[i] ) ++count;
        }

        if ( count == k ) 
        {
            least_last = j;
        }           
    }

    if ( least_last != v.size() ) std::cout << v[least_last] << '\n';

    return 0;
}.
```

The program output is

```
2
```

The idea is to find the last position of the first element that occurs k-times. As soon as it is found the upper limit of the traversed sequence is set to this value. So if there is another element that occurs k-times before this limit then it means that it occurs the first compared with already found element.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggested solution! I didn't think to solve the problem this way, but is less complex than mine! I was trying to solve it with a O(n) complexity, but I wasn't even near it... thanks for the help!